# how can i execute a javascript function in my default browser with vb.net

Tags: javascript, vb.net-2010

I have a vb.net (2010) desktop application. I want to know if it is possible to create a function which will open an active browser and immediately triggers an javascript function. Maybe you guys can help me out, or give me some useful tips to keep me go a bit further in the right direction.

Comment: The [Process Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.71).aspx) is what you are looking for it can start a browser.
you will need to add more information and examples of what you have tried, if you want to get much help.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just to execute a specific javascript function. or do you wish it to load the website and fire a javascript function?

If it's just so you can run some JS you can use wscript shell or cscript shell. If it's to run  code from a specific site, this isn't possible

Comment: I want to load a website e.g. www.example.com/test.html inside that i have a javascript function "function Test(){alert("kjhsdfk")}" that i want to execute.

Comment: this isn't possible using pure vb.net to browser programming. what you could do is open the page to `/test.html?from=program` then in the pages JS check for `from=program` in the url and call the function if need be